# forward_list iterators incompatible

Tags: c++, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I'm trying to complete a program that evaluates polynomials when given an x-value.
The polynomials are stored using the STL's forward_list in objects of the class.

```
class PolyTerm {
   private:
      int _order = 0;
      double _coeff = 0.0;
   public:
      PolyTerm() = default;
      PolyTerm(int order, double coefficient) : _order(order), _coeff(coefficient) {}

      void setOrder(int order) { _order = order; }
      void setCoeff(double coeff) { _coeff = coeff; }

      int getOrder() const { return _order; }
      double getCoeff() const { return _coeff; }
};
```

My function which takes the object and the x-value is written as follows:

```
double evaluate(const forward_list<PolyTerm>& terms, double x) {
   double answer = 0;
   forward_list<PolyTerm>::iterator it;
   while (it != terms.end()) {
       answer += it->getCoeff() * pow(x, it->getOrder());
       it++;
   }
return answer;
}
```

My compiler doesn't show any errors but once I try to run the program, I get a pop-up saying "Debug Assertion Failed!" with Expression: forward_list iterators incompatible
[Image of pop-up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePVrI.png)
I'm pretty sure I declared the iterator to be of the same type as the list holding the polynomial so I'm not sure why I'm getting this error.

Can anyone explain to me what's wrong?
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 4):

`forward_list<PolyTerm>::iterator it;` it's not initialized. It must be initialized with the first element of the forward list.

```
forward_list<PolyTerm>::iterator it = terms.begin();
```

You may simplify you loop, and you will not use `it`

```
for (const auto& term : terms)
   answer += term.getCoeff() * pow(x, term.getOrder());
```

Answer (score 2):

You also could have used [std::accumulate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate), as that will enforce the initialization using the third argument to the function.  Also, since there is no need to declare and initialize iterators, there is no chance you will forget to initialize the iterator.

Here is an example.  Note that there are no hand-written loops:

```
  #include <numeric>
  //...
  double evaluate(const forward_list<PolyTerm>& terms, double x) 
  {
     return std::accumulate(terms.begin(), terms.end(), 0.0, // <-- Note the initial value is 0.0 -- you can't miss it
                            [&](double total, const PolyTerm& p) 
                              { return total + p.getCoeff() * pow(x, p.getOrder()); });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You never initialize `it`.

You should have used a `for` loop.

You should have used a C++11 `for(auto it: terms)` as I think it would go.